# MySQL: Trying to insert a value in a timestamp throws an error

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a table with this column:

> last_modified timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

And it looks like I can not insert a row with a custom timestamp, I get this error:

> Incorrect datetime value: '1145868501' for column 'last_modified' at row 1

I am trying to populate this table with data coming from another table, that other table only has a creation_time field which is a DATETIME so I use UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creation_time) to populate the timestamp.

I think the timestamp column with "DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" prevents me from inserting my own stuff, am I right? If yes where is the official doc about that, and what is the best solution? Creating a simple timestamp first then alter the table after inserting data?

Thanks!

EDIT: since people are advising me to not use UNIX_TIMESTAMP, I have to say that I didn't want to use that at the beginning, but I got this kind of error:
Incorrect datetime value: '2010-03-28 02:15:51' for column 'last_modified'
So I thought I had to insert a "real" timestamp...

Comment: Tried it without wrapping `creation_time` with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Actually it's what I tried first, it didn't work either :-(

Comment: What happened? How did it not work?

Comment: If you don't need the special features of `TIMESTAMP` why not change it to `DATETIME`?

Comment: I need them, the thing is I need to populate this table with existing data first, then the timestamp the way I declare is exaclty what I want for future data. Otherwise I feel like it doesn't work for 2010-03-28 02:15:51 but it worked with 2010-10-11 11:11:11 for instance...

Comment: Maybe FROM_UNIXTIME SQL function will be helpful? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can explicitedly insert a value in a `TIMESTAMP` column. Read: [TIMESTAMP Properties](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp.html)

> The auto-update TIMESTAMP column, if there is one, is automatically updated to the current timestamp when the value of any other column in the row is changed from its current value. If all other columns are set to their current values, the TIMESTAMP column does not change. Automatic updating does not apply if the TIMESTAMP column is explicitly assigned a value other than NULL.

---

**Update**

Hehe, the error occurs because - well- there was no datetime with `'2010-03-28 02:15:51'`! This was in the daylight saving time gap (which usually appears some day in March, between `02:00 - 03:00` or `03:00 - 04:00`.

See: [Daylight Saving Time](http://www.webexhibits.org/daylightsaving/b.html) explanation.

Comment: You need to know which timezone was used for storing these datetimes.

Comment: I am afraid I have to fix those dates one by one, the DB has been hosted on several servers for the last 5 years. Anyway I shouldn't have too many rows with this problem. Thanks to everybody who took time to help me!

Comment: MySQL `TIMESTAMP` solves this problem by storing only UTC values (and showing/inserting depending on the server's timezone). If your servers have been in different timezones and you were using `DATETIME` columns, not timestamps, then you'll need to convert the data, separately for the separate servers - so you don't get (plus/minus) a few hours differences.

Comment: No matter how many times I run into problems like these related to the standard/daylight savings time transition, I seem to repress them until they happen again. Thanks for reminding me, despite how painful it is to be reminded. :)

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to put a long integer into a datetime field. That doesn't work. Remove the call to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` and it should work.

The MySQL `TIMESTAMP` type is almost identical to a `DATETIME`; it just has some extra auto-update magic. As far as SELECT and UPDATE is concerned, it is a `DATETIME`.

Comment: Not only auto-update, but the timezones magic (which is much more important feature)

Comment: Yes. But my point is that it isn't a Unix integer timestamp. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the column is always auto-updated, you can remove the property, getters and setters from the Entity. 
Doing this way, it will be ignored in all queries.